# Proof of FLOPS of matrix inverse by companion matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, companion-matrices

I was wondering if anyone could help me prove that the cost of matrix
inversion by companion matrix is $2n^3$ + L.O.T. FLOPS.

Comment: I know "matrix inversion"; I know what is a "companion matrix" (I have tought them at University level) but I don't know what is "matrix inversion by companion matrix" and I must not be alone... You should first direct us to an information explaining this method. Besides, what have you tried ? Where are you blocked ?

Comment: To be honest with you, I don't really understand the question myself. I have a list of proofs I need to remember for an upcoming exam, and I missed the lectures that explained this proof, so I'm just hoping someone knows what my lecturer was talking about.

Comment: I appreciate this honest answer. I have been looking around to find something on the net, but have not found relevant information.